# Query for top trending things in bigquery?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have daily revenue data for multiple locations. Here is an example:

```
+---------+------------+----------+------------+
|    ID   |  location  |  value   | timestamp  |
+---------+------------+----------+------------+
| 1       | LA         |  15.000  | 2019-02-12 |
| 2       | SF         |  23.000  | 2019-02-10 |
| 3       | NYC        |  9.000   | 2019-02-10 |
| 4       | LA         |  2.500   | 2019-02-09 |
+---------+------------+----------+------------+
```

I want to find the top three trending locations. The output should look like that:

```
+----------+------------+----------+----------------+
|   rank   |  location  |  growth  | growth_percent |
+----------+------------+----------+----------------+
| 1        | SF         |  23.000  | 0.75           |
| 2        | LA         |  17.500  | 0.62           |
| 3        | NYC        |  9.000   | 0.43           |
+----------+------------+----------+----------------+
```

I think using `RANK()` function can solve this problem. I started with:

```
SELECT location, 
  RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY location ORDER BY timestamp) as rank
FROM `revenues`
GROUP BY location, timestamp
```

But this returns a location multiple times. Any thoughts on how I can create such trending query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
WITH `data` AS(
  SELECT 1 AS ID, 'LA' AS location, 15000 AS value, '2019-02-12' AS timestamp UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 AS ID, 'SF' AS location, 23000 AS value, '2019-02-10' AS timestamp UNION ALL
  SELECT 3 AS ID, 'NYC' AS location, 9000 AS value, '2019-02-10' AS timestamp UNION ALL
  SELECT 4 AS ID, 'LA' AS location, 2500 AS value, '2019-02-09' AS timestamp
)

SELECT
  RANK() OVER (ORDER BY SUM(value) DESC) AS rank,
  location,
  SUM(value) AS growth
FROM `data`
GROUP BY
  location
```

Which results in:

```
[
  {
    "rank": "1",
    "location": "SF",
    "growth": "23000"
  },
  {
    "rank": "2",
    "location": "LA",
    "growth": "17500"
  },
  {
    "rank": "3",
    "location": "NYC",
    "growth": "9000"
  }
]
```

By grouping the locations you remove the duplication observed in your query.

Comment: Thanks Willian! How can I include the timestamp in the result to make the result filterable by time?

Comment: As there's the aggregation step then some function would have to be applied to the timestamp as well in order to bring one representative value, such as applying `max`   or `min`.